# How Can I Count occurrences that immediately follow another event in SQL?

Tags: sql, count, range

I have taken a data set and run the following query to filter it to the events that I want:

```
SELECT player_id, team_id, pbp_id, event_desc_id 
FROM GamsetPBP 
WHERE event_desc_id = '2FGM' OR event_desc_id = '3FGM' OR event_desc_id = '2FGA' OR event_desc_id ='3FGA' OR event_desc_id = 'O';
```

When I do this, it shows all the instances of those events. I want to count all instances where a 2FGM, 3FGM, 2FGA, or 3FGA occurs within two events of an 'O' event based on the pbp_id.

So if an 'O' has a pbp_id of 45 and there is a '2FGM' with a pbp_id of 47, I want to be able to count it. Any suggestions on how I can Count occurrences within a range like this?

Comment: (1) Do you want to count events for the same player or for the same team or just for the whole table (that would not make much sense). (2) What is the primary key of your table? (3) Can you provide sample data and the desired output for that data? (4) What has 47 to do with 45?

Comment: mySQL? SQLServer, Oracle, DB2? what engine and version?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you could use this query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT a.pbp_id)
FROM       GamsetPBP a
INNER JOIN GamsetPBP b
        ON b.pbp_id BETWEEN a.php_id + 1 AND a.php_id + 2
       AND b.event_desc_id IN ('2FGM', '3FGM', '2FGA', '3FGA')
       -- ... any other join conditions on player_id? team_id?
WHERE      a.event_desc_id = 'O';
```

This counts the number of "O" events that have an event following it with an ID that is one or two greater, and which have a type that is '2FGM', '3FGM', '2FGA', or '3FGA'. There could of course be two of those following, but then the above query will only count that as one instance.

If you want to count such "doubles" separately, then remove the word `DISTINCT`.

From your comment it became clear that the two records (the one with "O" and the one with the other type) should belong to the same team and be counted per team, with the highest counts listed first.

In that case add the team condition in the `join`, select the team ID, group by it and order by the count:

```
SELECT     a.team_id,
           COUNT(DISTINCT a.pbp_id)
FROM       GamsetPBP a
INNER JOIN GamsetPBP b
        ON b.pbp_id BETWEEN a.php_id + 1 AND a.php_id + 2
       AND b.event_desc_id IN ('2FGM', '3FGM', '2FGA', '3FGA')
       AND b.team_id = a.team_id
WHERE      a.event_desc_id = 'O'
GROUP BY   a.team_id
ORDER BY   2 DESC;
```

Comment: This worked great for counting the total number of occurrences so thank you for the tip! It took my data set from over 40,000 to 600 which was within the range I was expecting. Is there an easy way to list out all the pbp_id instances where this occurred? Or more specifically, I am hoping to see how many times it occurred for each team.id, so I could see of those 600 occurrences which teams had the most and which had the least

Comment: I modified the second query in my answer to provide a count per team, and list them with highest counts first.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I was also able to use a similar query to run it by player. I appreciate the help!